# When do we consider a boolean expression "fully simplified"? (Eg, is $B'+ BA'C$ the simplest form of $AB'C + A'BC+ A'B'C+A'B'C'+AB'C'$?)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

Edit:

I have simplified a boolean expression (see below) and there still some terms who share the same element (it is very hard to simplify more). So,

> When do we consider a boolean expression to be "fully simplified" (can't be simplified anymore)?

Here is an example:

> $$AB'C + A'BC+ A'B'C+A'B'C'+AB'C'$$
> where ($'$) means "not". For this example, I think the expression can not be simplified more than this: $$B'+ BA'C$$

So, is there any way to make sure the expression can't be simplified any more?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Wake up.  That is not an algebraic expression.   What sort of expression is it?

Answer (score 1):

In this case there is a further simplification you can make, viz to $B + A'C$.

In general, the problem of finding the simplest of the expressions that are equivalent to a given boolean expression is a hard one. [3-SAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem#3-satisfiability) is NP-complete, and that is only a subset of the general problem. In 3-SAT, the expression is the "and" of some terms, each of which is the "or" (or $+$ in your notation) of three variables, any of which might be negated. Something like this: $$(A+B+C)(A'+C'+D)(C+D'+E)$$ Then the task is to find whether or not the given expression is "satisfiable" or not. "The expression is not satisfiable" is equivalent to "The expression is equivalent to False". If the expression is not equivalent to False, 3-SAT does not ask for the simplest equivalent expression. So the general problem of finding the simplest equivalent expression is at least as hard as 3-SAT.

Comment: Additionally, what's the metric of "simplicity"? Total terms? Total variables? Do we count multiplication differently than addition?

Comment: @Rosie F,  thanks for your comment, I already know the most simplified expression for the expression, just wanted to test your answers with it, whatever, I actually didn't get your answer, could you be more clear

Comment: @UserUser: *"I already know the most simplified expression for the expression, just wanted to test your answers with it"* ... (Pardon the lecture, but ...) Please don't do that. The folks here are *volunteers*, not *test subjects*. In general, withholding what you know about a problem is inconsiderate, as it can cause people to waste their valuable time explaining things you already understand instead of engaging you about the things you don't (or just moving on to another question whose asker actually needs help). ... Okay, lecture over. :) Good luck to you.

Comment: @Blue, thanks for your comment, but what I held doesn't really affect the result, I did not ask to solve that expression, I asked how to judge whether or not it is the simplest, I wouldn't do that if it will obstruct them from giving the right answer. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Vietch Diagram supporting the logic of reduction to   $\quad\textbf{B'+A'C}$

[image]

Note how I labeled the (A,A), (B,B'), (C,C') cells outside the big rectangle so they overlap. The result you seek comes from taking the largest rectangular area(s) found after entering the data.

Note the rectangle for terms $(5,1,3,4)\implies B')\quad$ and $\quad (2,3)\implies A'C$.

I did this in EXCEL, entering, for example $\quad 1(AB'C)\quad$ because it let me keep track of which terms had been entered, and verify they afterward. Note, If $A'C$ had been in the original terms, you would have had  to enter it in the cells currently occupied by $2$ and $3$. You'll have to develop your own means of keeping track of stuff. This just works for me and I'm $70$.  I hope this helps explain the usage of Vietch diagrams.

Comment: I appreciate your comment, but this tool doesn't give the right answer

Comment: I updated my answer, skipping the tool and using logic to reduce the logic. :)

Comment: thanks for your comment, but the answer I provided is not the most simplified form of the expression, means there is one more step that needs to be taken to get the most simplified form

Comment: @UserUser I have updated my answer using a Vietch diagram instead of a Karnaugh map. I find the latter harder to understand.

Comment: thanks again for your comment, what an amazing and short method, I hope I can learn it, could you please explain it or provide a link so I can watch how it's done!!

Comment: @UserUser I  updated my answer with a better explanation of how to use one of these diagrams. You start with $2^n$ cells with elements such as A,B,C where, for instance, the cells for A overlap both B and B'. All terms overlap the x,x' of the other terms. I put black borderlines just outside the positive A,B,C terms and left the borders for A'B'C' blanks just so I could spot them easily.